# Error while implementing function for search in ListView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I was implementing searching in a list view  but failing badly, then got a piece of code from a YOUTUBE video reference but its in **JAVA** but I'm working with **KOTLIN**.

When I was converting it, again I was failing. Can you help me with **KOTLIN** code for this **JAVA** code

```
 @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
                    filterResults.count = countryModelsList.size();
                    filterResults.values = countryModelsList;

                }else{
                    List<CountryModel> resultsModel = new ArrayList<>();
                    String searchStr = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

                    for(CountryModel itemsModel:countryModelsList){
                        if(itemsModel.getCountry().toLowerCase().contains(searchStr)){
                            resultsModel.add(itemsModel);

                        }
                        filterResults.count = resultsModel.size();
                        filterResults.values = resultsModel;
                    }


                }

                return filterResults;
            }
```

The place where I was failing was to implement override methods

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you get by running the [convert to Koltin functionality built into android studio](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/add-kotlin#convert).

```
    val filter: Filter
        get() {
            val filter: Filter = object : Filter() {
                protected fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
                    val filterResults = FilterResults()
                    if (constraint == null || constraint.length == 0) {
                        filterResults.count = countryModelsList.size()
                        filterResults.values = countryModelsList
                    } else {
                        val resultsModel: List<CountryModel> = ArrayList<Any>()
                        val searchStr = constraint.toString().toLowerCase()
                        for (itemsModel in countryModelsList) {
                            if (itemsModel.getCountry().toLowerCase().contains(searchStr)) {
                                resultsModel.add(itemsModel)
                            }
                            filterResults.count = resultsModel.size()
                            filterResults.values = resultsModel
                        }
                    }
                    return filterResults
                }
            }
        }
```

If this does not work feel free to reply with more of your code, or the link to the youtube video and i'll try to give it another look.